# Maven Test Execution by Tags with JUNIT5 and Surefire

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, tagging

I have test and tagged the tests by the @Tag annotation from the *org.junit.jupiter.api* package.

This is the pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <groups>one</groups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
@Tag("one")
public class BubblegumApiIT {
   // SOME TEST CODE
}
```

Now I want to execute just the tests that are tagged by "one". When I configure the JUNIT with Intellj (*instead of 'CLASS' I use 'TAGS'*) **it works.**
However, the equivalent *mvn* command **does not work.**

The equivalent maven command would be *mvn -Dgroups=one test* or?

But I am executing exactly 0 tests then.

Anybody had this issue before?

Comment: Hello, Does mvn command run the tests if you don't use the tags at all?

Comment: The naming convention for surefireplugin is that unit tests are named like `*Test.java` which integration tests are executed by maven-failsafe-plugin which are named like `*IT.java`... so if this test is a unit test you should name it accordingly...

Comment: BTW: Upgrade surefire plugin to most recent version (3.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:

- "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
- "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
- "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
- "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".

Your test class do not follow the default wildcard patterns. Either rename it or specify in the plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>ReservationApiIT.java</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```